# Generic type on object

Tags: typescript, object, generics, types

I have a simple class that allows setting and getting generic values to a class object (imagine that this class is provided by an NPM package).

```
class Spec {
    protected data = {};
    set<T>(k: string, v: T) {
        this.data[k] = v;
    }
    get(k: string) {
        return this.data[k];
    }
}
```

Let's say I create an instance of this class and set an `id` field of type `number`:

```
const spec = new Spec();
spec.set('id', 100);
```

When I retrieve this value, TypeScript returns the value as type `any` instead of `number`:

```
const id = spec.get('id');
// id should be of typescript type number (any instead)
```

I can manually specify the type but I would like to get handled this automatically:

```
const id = spec.get<number>('id');
// or
const id = spec.get('id') as number;
```

Is there a hack for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way I can think of is if `Spec` had a generic parameter to represent the type for `data` and when `set` is called, `this` is returned but with it's type modified to reflect the newly added field. The problem with this approach is that you need to either make all the  calls to `set` before assigning the value to a variable, or hold each subsequent result of `set` in a new variable as it will have a different type.

```
class Spec<TAll = {}>{
  protected data: TAll = {} as any;
  set<TKey extends string, TValue>(k: TKey, v: TValue): Spec<TAll & { [P in TKey]: TValue }> {
    (this.data as any)[k] = v;
    return this as any
  }
  get<TKey extends keyof TAll>(k: TKey) {
    return this.data[k];
  }
}


const spec = new Spec().set('id', 100);

spec.get('id') // is number
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks perfect.